# egrep -f regexlist inputfile: show unused patterns in regexlist

Tags: regex, grep

`egrep -f regexlist inputfile` shows me all lines in `inputfile` that
match any regular expression in `regexlist`.

I want to know if any of the lines in `regexlist` are unused.

In other words, which lines (regular expressions) can I remove from
`regexlist` to get the same results?

Is there an efficient way to do this? I can think of several
inefficient ways (eg, testing each pattern one at a time, or even
using `egrep -v` to trim down inputfile or something).

Slightly trickier problem: how to efficiently find redundant lines in
`regexlist`? In other words, regular expressions that *do* match lines
in `inputfile`, but only lines that are already matched by other
regular expressions in `regexlist`.

Comment: That's a good question. I would doubt there are pre-built tools for this but if you were writing grep yourself (or editing it) you might be able to keep track of that information relatively cheaply (at least for the first part, the second is going to be costly no matter how you do it I think as you need to keep a list of all lines matched by each pattern and constantly compare those lists).

Comment: I could write an egrep that compares each line in `inputfile` to each regex in `regexlist` but that seems really costly. Surely egrep is more efficient (in which case writing my own is probably a bad idea). I suppose I could remove a pattern from the list of patterns to check once it's been matched, but still seems much uglier.

Comment: I imagine there might be regex analyzing tools that could be used to find entirely redundant patterns (that is patterns that only ever match things some other pattern already matches) but I don't know of any offhand. I wasn't actually suggesting writing your own grep my point was more that without being *in* the grep/etc. process I can't think of any non-costly ways to do it. But *if* you are in the process then the tracking necessary for that shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -vf outputfile regexlist
```

Where `outputfile` is derived via `egrep -of regexlist inputfile > outputfile`.

Is this an acceptable solution, given that I am asking you to use the -o switch in your first grep?

How it works:

1. Using the `-o` switch you match only the exact strings (and not entire lines) that match the string you provide in the file `regexlist`.
2. You capture the matches within file `outputfile`. The `outputfile` contains only those strings that were found in your `inputfile`.
3. You print out all the lines that DO NOT match any lines in inputfile from your regexlist using the -v switch of grep (print all lines that do not match). These were the lines from `regexlist` that never matched anything from `inputfile`

**Note:** I realised during the course of this answer that this works for regular strings present in `regexlist` and not to actual regular expressions.

Comment: It took me a few seconds to see why this works. Maybe add a brief explanation? It's fairly obvious when you know, but as an answer, this is potentially puzzling. Still, upvote from me.

Comment: Sure, edited. Also realised a rather significant limitation :(
I used to use this technique on strings, not exactly regular expressions.